# Load dynamic library with new link-list map on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, shared-libraries, dynamic-loading

I have a C++ code which loads dynamic libraries via the dlmopen() function with the LM_ID_NEWLM Lmid_t. The code compiles and works as expected on Linux, but it fails on Mac OS. I struggle to obtain the same behaviour with the dlopen() function. Extensive search on Google did not reveal any obvious solutions to the problem. The suggestion to use

> dlopen("somesharedlibrary.dylib", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GROUP | RTLD_LOCAL)

does not work since the RTLD_GROUP option is not recognised on Darwin. Is there a way to load a dynamic library with a new link-list map on Mac OS X?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, there is no way of doing that on Mac OS X, but why are you trying to accomplish that? i.e. what thing is requiring that you use separate link maps? If you're compiling on a new platform you should be able to control the libraries you're using, and thus minimize the use of multiple versions of the same library which is one of the primary reasons for the separate link maps.

Comment: @Petesh I am trying to load 2 independent instances of the same library. As an example: somesharedlibrary.dylib should be dynamically loaded twice and initialised independently. How can this be done on a Mac OS X?

Comment: To accomplish this in Mac OS x, link to the library explicitly, make sure that the .dylib references the explicit library you want to use and use RTLD_LOCAL for the loading. But a library that anticipates being loaded multiple times and relies on OS chicanery (and this is really chicanery) to load it into a separate link space is just asking for trouble.